# Assign a value of the pressed div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanna create something like pixel art notepad but I can't get background-color from my divs(top left corner) when I am pressing on them and assign this value to the variable, then assign this value to the  "current color" div(top right corner).
[The screenshot of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii35G.png).

**My code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  createGrid(16);
  $('#newGrid').click(function() {
    refreshGrid();
  });
  $('.colorBoxes').click(function() {
    var currentObject = event.target;
    console.log(currentObject);
    //here i'm trying to get the color of my clicked div
    //(I'm really have no idea what to do)
    variable = window.getComputedStyle(currentObject);
    var containerForBackgroundColor = variable.getPropertyValue('background-color');
    console.log(containerForBackgroundColor);
  });
});
```

Comment: We hate images! `:(`

Comment: Please read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular *[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* Do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited question.

Comment: What debugging have you tried? What were the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using jQuery, you can access the background-color with the following code:

```
var containerForBackgroundColor = $(this).css('background-color');
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but now i have another error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment.

    $('#currentColor').css('background-color') = 
    containerForBackgroundColor;

Comment: @Stas You're trying to assign the value to the background of #currentColor, correct?

If so, use the following code:

$('#currentColor').css('background-color', containerForBackgroundColor);